# Javascript confirmation box

Tags: html, types, field, bootbox

I have a form with few inputs and all those inputs are required..I am using bootstrap..

Sample

```
<input type="email" require="yes">
```

It works fine it ask for a proper email if it is empty a little warming appears saying wrong email format or this field is required.

All this check happens when the user clicks on submit button... what on the submit button I also want to 
add a confirm box like "Are sure ? "...

I added the confirm action using bootbox and it works fine but my problem is that:

When the users click the inputs are checked the warning appears for a second and the confirm box too ... so my problem is that I dont want the confirm box appears unless all the inputs pass the checks ..

Thanks I hope I was clear...

```
 <script src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    // Confirm Box ..
    $(document).on("click", ".confirm", function(e) {
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
          console.log("Confirm result: "+result);
        });
    });
</script>


<input type="email" placeholder="email"  class="contact-input" required="yes">
<button id="contact-input" name="request_meet" class="btn btn-primary confirm">Send</button>
```

Comment: Which validation library are you using? And do you write any code for validation?

Comment: Not entirely clear, there isn't enough info to reproduce your problem. Could you provide exactly how you are doing these warnings and confirmations?

Comment: You will have to write a bunch of if statements in javascript, which basically will check for the various actions being completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a submit event to your button in javascript you can catch the submit before opening the confirm:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    if (!$('#emailField').val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```